# JQueryMobile: pagecontainershow on a particular page not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

JQueryMobile 1.4 has [deprecated](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show) the pageshow event and instead recommends using pagecontainershow; however, while I'm able to get the pagecontainershow event at a document level, I can't bind a function to a particular page.

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
...
<script>
  $( "#page1" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log("page1 pagecontainershow");
  } );
</script>
</div>
```

Demonstration: http://jsbin.com/IFolanOW/22/edit?html,console,output

I also considered using the alternative form of the jQuery "on" function where we use a selector, but that would need to be a parent of the page div, and that might include other pages, so that doesn't work.

As a workaround, I've done this, but it is very inefficient:

```
function registerOnPageShow(pageId, func) {
    var strippedPageId = pageId.replace("#", "");
    var e = "pagecontainershow." + strippedPageId;
    // TODO why isn't it working to use $(pageId) instead of $(document)?
    $( document ).off(e).on(e, null, {page: strippedPageId, f: func}, function(e, ui) {
      if ($(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id == e.data.page) {
        e.data.f(e, ui);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Stick to current events until they are removed on 1.5.

Comment: I've reported an issue regarding this and did some experiments. Check demos in last comment. I really cant understand why page events are deprecated and will be removed on 1.5 https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6865

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6865#issuecomment-31394425 if statement should be used.

Comment: @Omar Thank you for your investigation. So it looks like we have to bind to the pagecontainer's show and then check if the toPage is the one we want. The github issue points to the example but interesting is that I can only bind to $(document) instead of :mobile-container: http://jsbin.com/IFolanOW/21/edit

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately `if` is involved which is hectic. This is giving limited control over pages, especially the ones created dynamically. The default page container is `body`, but still you need to delegate event using `$(document).on("pagecontainershow", $.mobile.pageContainer, function () {});`. I really cant find no reason for deprecating page events, it's definitely a step back on jQM.

Comment: btw, `pagebeforeshow` and `pagebeforehide` aren't deprecated, use them instead.

Comment: `pagebeforeshow` and `pagebeforehide` are also deprecated events and shouldn't be used anymore. See [this comment](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6865#issuecomment-34059815).

Comment: Also be aware that `ui.prevPage` might be not valid on the first `pagecontainershow` event since there were no previous pages before. You could check this with a `if (ui.prevPage.length)` statement.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the page ID like this.

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function(e, ui) {
    var pageId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop('id');
});
```

There is currently no way to have a show/hide event on a specific page.

Comment: Deprecating something that useful and instead recommend using this??? u have any info?

Comment: No sorry, maybe you can file an issue here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I'm using (jqmobile >1.4):

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");

    var activePageId = activePage[0].id;
    switch (activePageId) {
        case 'loginPage':
            ...
            break;
        case 'homePage':
            ...
            break;
        case 'groupPage':
            ...
            break;
        default:
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(event, ui) {
   var pageId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop('id'),
       showFunc = pageId+'_show';

   if (typeof MobileSite[showFunc] == 'function') {
      MobileSite[showFunc]();
   }
});
```

MobileSite is contained in an external .js file with all the show() functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function (event, ui) {

    if (typeof ui.toPage == "object") {
      var crrentPage =   ui.toPage.attr("id") 

            }
});
```

and you must use this code before calling Index.js !!